# Button within ForEach Loop

Tags: ios, xcode, button, swiftui

I am creating an autocomplete search TextField. Currently, it is a VStack of categories and I want the user to tap a category to select it, and have the category become the TextField value.

This code works, but it is just text and nothing happens on tap:

```
var body: some View {
...
    Form {
        ...
        ForEach(observed.results, id: \.id) {
                Text($0.result).foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        ...
    }
...
}
```

When I try to turn them into buttons, XCode throws a `Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure` error.
`$search` is the `TextField`'s `text` attribute value.

```
@State private var search: String = ""
...
func setSearch(selected: String) {
        self.search = selected
    }
...
var body: some View {
...
    Form {
        ...
        ForEach(observed.results, id: \.id) {
            Button( action: { self.setSearch(selected: $0.result) }) {
                Text($0.result).foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
        ...
    }
...
}
```

How can I change state to update text field on tap?

Comment: You can always use a tap gesture instead of a button

.onTapGesture{
        self.setSearch(selected: $0.result)
    }

Comment: Adding onTapGesture to the Text (following foregroundColor) throws the same error as Button.

Comment: you need to include more code, this is something incredibly basic and the issue is probably occurring somewhere you are not showing us

Comment: I fixed it, and the fix was contained by the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Changing my `Form` to `List` produced more descriptive errors.
2. Used an explicit argument for my ForEach loop.

- I intended `$0` to be an implicit argument from my ForEach loop. However, when used within another closure, e.g. `Button { }` or `.onTapGesture() { }`, the nested closure threw an error believing the implicit argument to belong to itself.